# Spark structured streaming asynchronous batch blocking

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I’m using Apache Spark structured streaming for reading from Kafka. Sometimes my micro batches get processed in a greater time than specified, due to heavy writes IO operations. I was wondering if there’s an option of starting the next batch before the first one has finished, but make the second batch blocked by the first?

I mean that if the first one took 7 seconds and the batch is set for 5 seconds, then start the second batch on the fifth second. But if the second batch finishes block it so it won’t write before it’s previous batch (because of the will to keep the correct messages order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Next batch only starts if previous completed. I think you mean term interval. It would become a mess otherwise.

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers

Answer (score 0):

You can try run batch process in the separate thread. But for now there is no guruanee that the incoming batch resources will be available.

There will also be problems with restoring the job in case of failure (checkpointing streaming state before the batch is completed).

Obviously, there are no blockers that prevents to solve both problems... but for some reason asynchronous checkpointing was implemented only for Kafka